# Pipe - communicating with multiple forked child processes

Tags: c, pipe, fork, posix

I am writing a parent process, that needs to count events from a group of child processes.
I am going to use pipe() to achieve this.

Can I open a single pipe on the parent, and then fork 4 child processes that will use that same pipe to communicate with the parent, or must I create 4 different pipes? (1 for each child process)

It is important to state that the parent never communicates with the child processes. All it does is: Count and sum up the rate at which the child processes raise events.

Also: In case I can use a shared pipe, what would the atomicity of the messages be. Do I have to keep them one byte long, or can I assume that two 4 byte messages will not get their bytes interpolated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - named pipe for multiple forked children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772728/c-named-pipe-for-multiple-forked-children)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a single pipe.

You don't need to limit yourself to single-byte events.

[`man 7 pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) on Linux states:

> **PIPE_BUF**
>
> POSIX.1 says that [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)s of less than `PIPE_BUF` bytes must be
>   atomic: the output data is written to the pipe as a contiguous
>   sequence.  Writes of more than `PIPE_BUF` bytes may be nonatomic: the
>   kernel may interleave the data with data written by other processes.
>   POSIX.1 requires `PIPE_BUF` to be at least 512 bytes.  (On Linux,
>   `PIPE_BUF` is 4096 bytes.)

(Related: The [description of `write` in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html).)

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the basis for that quotation's claim about atomicity of writes to a pipe, and it does not seem consistent with some of the commentary in the Linux manual for `write()`, which seem to say that a partial write can occur in the event that a signal is received.  Do you know what that doc is referencing?

Comment: @JohnBollinger The open group link given in the answer states `Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less shall not be interleaved with data from other processes doing writes on the same pipe.`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, that's a quote from the Linux manual page for `pipe()`.  I'm asking about the *basis* for its claim, in POSIX, which I (still) have not been able to find.

Comment: No, the "description of write in POSIX" link to https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use one datagram unix socket pair created with [`socketpair`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) instead of a pipe. In this case each `write` creates a separate datagram and each `read` returns one datagram only. This way messages can be larger than `PIPE_BUF` and still be atomic.

Comment: Do you know how datagram performance compares to pipes? Would there be a significant difference?

Answer (score -2):

Try using named pipe is this example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/named-pipe-fifo-example-c-program/  Rin the reader and then the written should do the work, you should also think about message quue that is asynchronous way of communicating between process